# What is the default folder for temporary files spark uses on Windows?

Tags: windows, apache-spark

Does anyone know why Spark choose C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp as a default folder for temporary files, but not C:\tmp or anything else? In official docs there just a couple words about \tmp folder, but it's applicable for example for Linux, not Windows.

Comment: Because that's the default temp dir for everything on Windows

Answer (score 1):

May be it just using default environment variable %TMP% or %TEMP%?

Comment: It was also my suggestion and I didn't find any proof for that.

Comment: @ConstantineKopylovich, see [`GetTempPathW`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-gettemppathw). Normally the default user profile defines the `TEMP` and `TMP` variables as `"%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp"`. A user can modify the default values, or even remove the definitions. In the latter case the user gets the system-variable value, `"%SystemRoot%\Temp"`. This directory allows standard users to create files and subdirectories, to which the user is granted full control. However, it's not as isolated and secure as the default directory in the user profile.

Comment: @ConstantineKopylovich, note that if the `TMP` or `TEMP` variable isn't defined, typically because a process has a modified environment, then `GetTempPathW` defaults to `USERPROFILE`, and if that's not defined it defaults to `SystemRoot`. The latter doesn't work for standard users. I think they should have addressed this back in Vista (2006) by moving the system temp directory to `"%ProgramData%\Temp"` and then making that the only default path returned by `GetTempPathW` if neither `TEMP` nor `TMP` is defined. This would be simpler, more consistent, and more reliable than the old behavior.

Comment: @ErykSun, If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it and mark as useful. Thank you again :)